# Synchronizing threads using condition variables (monitors)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, race-condition, monitors

I need to synchronize multiple threads (using POSIX threads). Moreover, I am making use of condition variables (monitors) to achieve that.

The issue is that I must implement a "first come first served" strategy. Say multiple threads are waiting for another thread to signal that condition change, does the [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) call put the threads in a queue itself or should I define an explicit queue to achieve this? A possible solution to this might also be making use of locks.

Comment: What is *"first come first served" strategy* about? The threads or the data produced by those? If it's about threads - rethink your design (unless it is some academical task to proof you know what are you doing). If it's about data - just put the data into the queue and process the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The Pthreads API does not guarantee fairness for the `pthread_cond_wait` + `pthread_cond_signal`/`pthread_cond_broadcast` combo. The [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html) explicitly states that the scheduling policy will determine the order in which the waiting threads will wake up:

> If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the scheduling policy shall determine the order in which threads are unblocked.

If you don't want to rely on the scheduler (even if it's one that [has "aged well" like Linux' CFS](http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~sasha/papers/eurosys16-final29.pdf)), you need to control the parking and unparking yourself.

As for the implementation of a fair waiting queue, you can build on top of an [MCS queue](https://www.quora.com/How-does-an-MCS-lock-work).